# Need javascript to open site in new window

Tags: javascript, window

I need to adjust this script so that when you click on the slideshow, it opens another site in a new window. I'm not a programmer; I'm using a given code. Currently, the site opens within the slideshow boundary, showing only a portion of the site. Here is the current code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fineartamerica.com/slideshowmouseover.php?id=965568079&memberidtype=artistid&memberid=96556&width=400px&height=400px'></script>
<img id='faaslideshowimage[965568079]' onClick='javascript: mouseclick965568079(event);' onMouseOver='javascript: mouseover965568079();' onMouseOut='javascript: mouseout965568079();'src='http://fineartamerica.com/Blank.jpg' style='width: 400px; height: 400px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid #666666; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' alt='Art Prints' title='Art Prints'>
```

Comment: There are enough popup browsers than opening new windows is .. tricky at best.  Opening things in a floating `<div>...</div>` or `iframe` is far more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the `&width=400px&height=400px` if you don't want the window constrained. Also, I'd recommend removing the mouse events - I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but - as a user - I'd hate a window popping up every time I moused over/out of an element. My own preference there, but I think removing the width and height properties should get what you want, if I'm not mistaken.